# why do my simple arrays not work?

Tags: java, arrays

This program should ask how many of an animal are left in the wild 5 times. Then it should use a second method to output the same information. But i cant figure this out; every time i change anything based on previous questions here i just add to the number of errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class animals {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] q1 = question();
        output(q1);

        System.exit(0);

    } // exit main

    public static int[] question() {
        String[] wild = { "Komodo Dragon", "Mantee", "Kakapo", "Florida Panther", "White Rhino" };
        int number = 0;
        int[] record = {};
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(wild[number] + ":");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("How many are left in the wild?");
            int howMany = scanner.nextInt();
            record = new int[] {howMany};
            number++;

        }//end for loop

        return record;

    }// end method question

    public static void output(int[] q1){
        System.out.println("There are " + q1[0] +  " Komodo Dragons in the wild");
        System.out.println("There are " + q1[1] +  " Mantees in the wild");
        System.out.println("There are " + q1[2] +  " Kakapos in the wild");
        System.out.println("There are " + q1[3] +  " Florida Panthers in the wild");
        System.out.println("There are " + q1[4] +  " White Rhinos in the wild");
    }//end method output

} // end class animals
```

So this compiles alright, then when i've added 5 numbers in terminal after each loop i get

```
There are 3 Komodo Dragons in the wild
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at animals.output(animals.java:39)
    at animals.main(animals.java:13)
```

Other than the fact that im getting the text, the monodo dragon number being provided is the last number i input not the first

Comment: Please note that `System.exit(0)` is useless at the end of your main method.

Comment: I would start with code which compiles and as you add each line, make sure it compiles before adding more `int[number] record = {};` is never going to compile in which case, adding more code is just going to be increasing confusing.

Comment: Note: arrays start arrays 0 not 1. Every time you call `record = new int[] {howMany};` you replace the previous value. Only the last value is retained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't make sense

```
int[number] record = {};
```

most like what you meant was

```
int[] record = new int[wild.length];
```

and instead of

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
```

you need

```
for (int i = 0; i < wild.length; i++) {
```

instead of the following which creates an array of 1 value `[0]`

```
record = new int[] {howMany};
```

which will produce the following when you try to access `[1]`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

you need

```
record[i] = howMany;
```

As you write each line of code in your IDE (or your editor) you should see if that compiles and if it doesn't adding more lines is unlikely to help. I suggest you try to compile and test as often as possible so you know where the source of your errors are and when you get a bug, you can step through the code in your debugger to see why the program is not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

`int number = 0;
   int[] record = new int[5];`

and another modification which you need to make:

`int howMany = scanner.nextInt();
  record[number] = howMany;`

Remove comment from last line.

Now your program should work fine.

Learn some basic stuff about arrays.